# Not getting response from Express Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Not getting any response back from server upon requesting get/post to my server.
I tried playing around with orders within index.js but had no luck.
I tried with postman sending post to localhost:8080/register but it is stuck on sending request.

I am guessing this is due to either middleware holding it up, so I tried commenting out all the app.use other than authRouter but doesn't seem to be working in anyway.

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const db = require('./config/dbConfig');

const app = express();

const authRouter = require('./router/authRouter');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(authRouter);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

db.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server up and running @ ${PORT}`));
});
```

authRouter.js

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');
const router = Router();

router.get('/register', () => {
    authController.register_get;
});
router.get('/login', () => {
    authController.signin_get;
});
router.post('/register', () => {
    authController.register_post;
});
router.post('/login', () => {
    authController.signin_post;
});

module.exports = router;
```

authController.js

```
module.exports.register_get = (req, res) => {
    res.send('signup');
};

module.exports.register_post = (req, res) => {
    res.send('signup');
};

module.exports.signin_get = (req, res) => {
    res.send('signup');
};

module.exports.signin_post = (req, res) => {
    res.send('signup');
};
```

Comment: What exact request are you sending to your server?

Comment: @jfriend00 making post request with some random json body.

Comment: I was asking for exactly which URL you were using so we could examine that particular route, but then I saw that all your route definitions are wrong so I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Second argument to `router.post('/register', ...)` should be a function that will be invoked when the client sends a `POST` request to `/register` route.

You passed the function to `router.post(...)` method and inside that route handler function, you just have one statement:

```
authController.register_post;
```

This statement does nothing. You need to invoke the `register_post` function and pass in the `req` and `res` arguments to allow `register_post` function have access to the `Request` and `Response` objects.

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    authController.register_post(req, res);
});
```

or just pass the reference to `authController.register_post` function

```
router.post('/register', authController.register_post);
```

Comment: Thanks! like you said, I didn't realize I had to invoke these functions!

Comment: You are doing the same mistake in all other routes as well, don't forget to fix them as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually call your controller functions with the proper arguments.  So, change this:

```
router.get('/register', () => {
    authController.register_get;
});
```

To one of these:

```
router.get('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    authController.register_get(req, res, next);
});
```

or:

```
router.get('/register', authController.register_get);
```